# WooCommerce product attribute terms not in numeric order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've set the product attribute 'Size' to show the terms in numeric order, and in the dashboard they appear correctly, like so:

[image]

('0' being a temporary placeholder for when no size is given).

On the user-facing site, though, the terms render in almost numeric order, save for the term '8', which appears at the end for some reason:

[image]

Is there a reason for this and a way to change it?

Comment: Change order to custom and should return the order you have set. If custom ordering is selected the Attributes can be dragged and dropped into a specific order which would display across. Ofc could be a setting from the widget you use or the plugin w/e the case is.

Comment: The problem with custom ordering is that whenever I add new sizes the attributes will have to be manually reordered. There's not really anything special about the widget. It's just one of the vanilla WooCommerce blocks.

Comment: When you sort by title is is doing an alpha sort, not numeric so either use custom order or modify the widget how to sort titles.